# Make a .com program to call a .exe (like devenv.com)

Tags: com, exe

Devenv.com is the visual studio command line interface such that when you type `devenv /?` help for devenv appears on the console. However, with no options, devenv.com simply calls devenv.exe (the visual studio GUI).

How do I make a .com program in visual studio 2010?

Thanks

A.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Devenv.com isn't actually an executable that uses the COM file format.  It is simply an plain EXE that was just *renamed*.  Windows isn't otherwise fooled by it, it always looks a the header of the file.  The "MZ" prefix that's present in the header is enough to convince it that it is really an EXE file and is relocatable, it doesn't just go by the filename extension.

The only reason it exists is as a trick.  Based on the way the command processor looks for executable files.  If it has a choice between foo.com and foo.exe then it will pick foo.com first.

So when you type "devenv yadayada" at the command prompt then you get the console mode app, devenv.com, which reuses the console window.  Which, if necessary, launches devenv.exe

So simply build a normal .exe file.  And rename it to .com

Comment: I didn't think to try the obvious. This is a very useful technique!